# C# Regex for three digit and an alpha

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I have a field where I need to have a regex where the first 3 digits are numeric and the fourth character should be alpha- letter only, I need to have regex in both c# and javascript.

My following regex is good for three numeric number

```
@"\A(\d){3}\Z";
```

How to add for the fourth character which has to be alpha

Comment: You can write this `@"\A(\d){3}\Z";` regex and can not add a `alpha- letter` ?

Comment: the fourth charcter must be a letter A-Z

Answer (score 0):

If by alpha you mean only latin letters, you can do this:

```
^\d{3}[a-zA-Z]$
```

You can't use `\A` and `\Z` in JavaScript but they're equivalent to `^` and `$` unless you use the `m` option.

If you need full Unicode character range, use `\p{L}` instead of `[a-zA-Z]`, but you're out of luck for JavaScript support. You'd have to include the relevant Unicode ranges by hand into the character class...

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to know about is [Character Classes or Character Sets](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

> With a "character class", also called "character set", you can tell the regex engine to match only one out of several characters. Simply place the characters you want to match between square brackets. [...]

and

> [...] You can use a hyphen inside a character class to specify a range of characters. [0-9] matches a single digit between 0 and 9. You can use more than one range. [0-9a-fA-F] matches a single hexadecimal digit, case insensitively. You can combine ranges and single characters. [0-9a-fxA-FX] matches a hexadecimal digit or the letter X. Again, the order of the characters and the ranges does not matter. [...]

So basically you can match character "A" to "Z" by placing them in square brackets and using a hyphen to indicate range

```
[A-Z]
```

You can match multiple sets, so if you also need "a" to "z" (lowercase) you can include

```
[A-Za-z]
```

Comment: What about other letters like "ÖÜŞ" ? They are between A and Z depending on the culture.